# Converting generic Object to instanceof custom Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

Here is my code:

```
function Apple (taste)
{
    this.t = taste || null; 
}

var x = new Apple("yummy");
var str = JSON.stringify(x);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(str);
console.log(obj);

var t = Object.create(Apple, obj);

if (t instanceof Apple)
{
    console.log("its an apple");
}

console.log("end");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tTvy5/

What I can't figure out is that the members of `obj` are expected to be objects themselves? Surely it has to become primitives at some point?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for what? You're not asking a question. Are you thanking someone for writing your code for you?

Comment: I would think that after asking 150 questions, you'd know that this is a very low quality post. No question. No indication of where you're having trouble. Code is posted on a different site. I mean come on. At least pretend like you care.

Comment: @bfavaretto: IMO, you shouldn't fix questions for users like this. He's been a user for 4 years, 6 months. He should be able to do it himself. *(No offense to you.)*

Comment: I thought the code was self explanatory. I shall rephrase.

Comment: @squint You're right, I didn't notice. I won't rollback though. It's still NARQ, let's see if the OP will fix that.

Comment: @Ben: You're not using `Object.create` correctly. Please read the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [documentation for Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). The second parameter is not the object itself, but rather an object that describes the properties of the object.

So instead of `var t = Object.create(Apple.prototype, obj);`, you'll need an object that describes `obj`. Something like this might get you there:

```
var props = {};
for (var key in obj) {
    props[key] = { value: obj[key] };
}

var t = Object.create(Apple.prototype, props);
```